# Good links to learn network driver interfacing

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to know(study) about the network driver interfacing with the linux kernel or the TCP/IP stack.
 For this i would like to use my own system driver as a case study.
 Can you please tell me any good references from where i can study the above concept.
 I will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 2):

I recommend:

(1)One book "Understanding the Linux Network Internals" by Benvenuti; This book can be ordered on amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Network-Internals-Christian-Benvenuti/dp/0596002556](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596002556)

(2)One demo code inside the Linux Kernel source tree: ./drivers/net/pci-skeleton.c, or other real NIC driver codes inside the Linux Kernel, there are tons of NIC driver codes;

Comment: sir actually i don't have to write the driver i just want to know how the network driver interface with the tcp/ip stack, so that i can make my own stack and make changes so that driver uses my stack.Will the above books teach me these things?

Comment: + Related books: `Understanding the Linux kernel`, `Linux kernel drivers`.

Comment: I am sure this book will tell you everything that the Linux Network implementation. In fact, there are only several interfaces used between network device driver and the protocol stack, but there are complicated implementation behind the interfaces which programmer should be familiar with.

Comment: @tian_yufeng Sir is there any online pdf download for this?any way really thanks for the guidance

Comment: I think it's illegal to download pdf. Because the author does not authorize to do this.

Comment: @tian_yufeng Sir i studied some part of the book you mentioned but i am not getting the api's,function that are used by network driver to interface with TCP/IP stack is there any other book for that?

Comment: You can read following chapters first. The chapter 10, Frame Reception, page 210 is for packet receiving; Chapter 5, Network Device Initialization, page 84 is for device initialization; Chapter 8;

Comment: @tian_yufeng Sir i need some of your help can you please drop a mail to me on cloverobert@gmail.com,as i have some queries to ask you please...

Comment: Okey, I have sent to you email.

Comment: @tian_yufeng I again sent u a mail

Comment: @tian_yufeng Please check mail

Comment: @tian_yufeng Again mailed u

Comment: @tian_yufeng Waiting for the reply of mail sir

Answer (score 0):

I think some parts of the interface are explained in Linux Device Drivers book.
You can get a legal and free copy here:
http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Have a look on the code example of a network device driver, it should show you how the interface between device driver and kernel network subsystem is working.